# Properly expand copied file names using XCOPY

Tags: windows-10, batch, xcopy

I've made a batch script that is set to copy all `.cpp` files from a location I have set. It can copy the files *and* retain the folder structure, but it isn't expanding the copied file names properly. I also have an older version that is able to do this, but it also copies *everything* from the target folder to the new folder. The goal of the new version is to **only** copy a specific file type.

Here is the syntax using `XCOPY` that properly expands file names, but copies all of the folder's contents:

```
ECHO D | XCOPY "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects" "Backup\Projects" /S /Q /N
```

Here is the new syntax that fails to expand the filenames of copied file types:

```
ECHO F | XCOPY "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\*.cpp" "Backup\Projects\" /S /Q /N
```

Here is an example of the abbreviated/unexpanded file names I get in the target directory:

`WRNM~1.CPP`.

I don't know if the prompt override command switches *(`/S /Q /N`)* are affecting this, but I need the prompts to be overridden by them due to the sheer number of files being copied.
I would also like to note that despite copying files with the newer syntax, I can still get `XCOPY` to copy them even if I define the target as a directory using the `D` switch.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution that meets all of my requirements using `ROBOCOPY` instead:

```
ROBOCOPY "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects" "Backup\Projects" *.cpp /S
```

You can append the `/E` switch to also copy empty folders if needed. I tried this before, but I misplaced the file type definition.

Further `ROBOCOPY` documentation from [SS64](https://ss64.com/):

https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Answer (score 0):

[xcopy on Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy)

> Creates copies by using the NTFS short file or directory names. /n is required when you copy files or directories from an NTFS volume to a FAT volume or when the FAT file system naming convention (that is, 8.3 characters) is required on the Destination file system. The Destination file system can be FAT or NTFS.

Your older version of xcopy didn't handle `/n` properly. Check `xcopy /?` with each to check whenever the option changed its meaning.

Comment: I don't think this will work with the structure of my code, I use `ECHO F | XCOPY %TARGET% %DESTINATION% /S /Q /N` as it is required to skip the copy prompt, `/N` tells the code to not copy existing targets if present so the switch is already in use. I tried placing [/n] multiple different ways and it only broke my code.

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli: You are wrong about `/N`. This answer is correct.

Comment: You claim it does @harrymc but @Seth didn't not provide an example on _where_ to place the switch. The answer may work, but unless I know where to place `/N` outside of the existing switch I have the answer isn't of much help.

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli the location doesn't change. Read the help. `/n` doesn't have anything to do with overwriting. Your `echo F` is also wrong as there is no input for `F` in the overwrite prompt.

Comment: I said _override_ @Seth, because if I use that structure for copying individual files it copies it and doesn't prompt me as intended but removing the switch then causes me to be prompted to choose yes or no. If using `/N` clearly controls the prompt I don't know how your use of it is any different. The switch also works in combination with `ECHO F`, if you do not define this than `XCOPY` won't know if you're copying a folder _(`D`)_, or a file _(`F`)_. I've used this structure for a couple of years and I have never once had issues with it when copying individual folders or files.

Comment: The `/n` switch doesn't change any prompt robocopy will throw at you. As mentioned check the help (your specific local one). Your're telling it to use 8.3 filenames, not display what it's copying and to only copy populated sub directories. To avoid the prompt about file or directory just use a path. Either prefix `.\` or suffix another `\`. Your "new" syntax probably eliminates the need, which would become apparent if you ran the command without your echo upfront and with output. There is no option to suppress the prompt for overwriting. Using `nnnnnnn` in your echo would be error prone.